# Does SetTimer function runs in background or goes to sleep?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, timer

In one of my projects I need to efficiently schedule different operations to be executed over and over, each operation has its own time interval.

I've been wondering, when I use the [SetTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906(v=vs.85).aspx) function, what happens in the background?

Is a new thread created?
Does it run in the background and eats my CPU? Or does it sleep until the OS awakens it when the time comes?
Is it OK to have a large amount of timers or is there a good reason to try and minimize their amount?

Thanks.

Comment: SetTimer doesn't create a new thread. What happens depend if you use timerproc (last parameter) or not.

Comment: could you further explain or redirect us curious programmers to somewhere with an explanation about what exactly happens there and how?

Comment: That would be too broad, encompassing OS scheduling, delta-queues, timer objects, Windows message queues, the assembly of WM_TIMER messages etc.   For more details, you should consult one of the good 'Windows Internals' books.

Answer (score 2):

> Is a new thread created?

No.

> Does it run in the background and eats my CPU?

No - try it.  set a timer and check the Task Manager.

> does it sleep until the OS awakens it when the time comes?

Yes.

> Is it OK to have a large amount of timers or is there a good reason to
>   try and minimize their amount?

With today's systems a lot of timers is not exactly a huge overhead, but you should think carefully about such a requirement..

Comment: Worth noting: If you specify a `TimerProc` callback, it is executed on the same thread that calls `SetTimer`. A consequence of this is, that you do not need to guard data that is read/written in the `TimerProc` against concurrent access.